# mockito is flattening list of single element array

Tags: java, mockito

This works as expected

```
when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(List.of(
          new Object[] {
              "123",
              new BigDecimal("100"),
              "5/24/2024"
          },
          new Object[] {
              "456",
              new BigDecimal("10000"),
              "9/17/2024"
          }));
assertThat(query.getResultList()).hasSize(2);
```

This doesn't work. `query.getResultList()` is returning `["456", new BigDecimal("10000"), "9/17/2024"]` instead of `[["456", new BigDecimal("10000"), "9/17/2024"]]`.

```
when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(List.of(
          new Object[] {
              "456",
              new BigDecimal("10000"),
              "9/17/2024"
          }));
assertThat(query.getResultList()).hasSize(1);
```

How can I make Mockito return the `list of object[]` I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not Mockito, the problem is that `List.of(Object[])` is treating the array *members* as the items to put into the list, not the array *itself*.

Remember that variadic methods like `List.of` are declared like `of(Object... elements)` and that when you call them like `List.of("one", "two", "three")` the parameters are bundled up into an array and passed as the `elements` parameter.

But you are also free to pass an array of `elements` directly, yourself. The problem is exacerbated in this case by the fact that the type is just `Object` which all the elements of the `Object[]` you're passing in trivially fulfill.

The easiest solution is probably not to use `List.of` in this case at all, and just construct the list you want the mock to return manually:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Object[] {
    "456",
    new BigDecimal("10000"),
    "9/17/2024"
});
when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(list);
```